# Can we use OR operator in MooTools/Jquery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, mootools

Can we use relational operator in mootools selectors ? Say for example I have two check boxes with different names.How can I get them both in single selector query.

Comment: for jQ try `input[name=foo][name=bar]`...

Comment: @webarto: That's an AND. And an impossible AND, at that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for mootools selector engine Slick, it's just the same as in jquery:

`document.getElements("div.foo, div.bar, div.bar a");`

or also known as `$$`.

`$$("div.foo,div.bar");  // vs $("div.foo,div.bar"); in jquery`

both frameworks try to adhere to [CSS 3 selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors) and expand them with edge cases like reverse combinators etc

Notice $ in mootools is an alias for `document.id`, which you can think of like a `document.getElementById`, not at all like the jquery function wrapper, it returns a single element. if you want to pick an element by id it's `document.id("someid")` and not `$("#someid")` or the much favoured mistake by jquery users coming into mootools of `$$("#someid")`. You can, though, use `$$("#someid,#anotherid")` to get a collection of elements by their ids.

Answer (score 1):

In JQuery you can input multiple selectors, divided by comma:

http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

```
$("div,span,p.myClass").whatever ...
```